# No sound in Hidden Folks (Unity engine game)

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, sound, games, steam

**Context:** Ubuntu 16.04.2 (64-bit) with sound over (NVIDIA GTX1070) HDMI to a receiver.

I don’t generally have problems with sound and I’ve played a few Unity engine games (32 and 64-bit) from Steam with no problem in the past, but with this game I get no sound at all. I’m following up with the developers, but their Linux release is fairly new and I suspect they don’t know too much about Linux in general.

I use Quod Libet with ALSA so a while ago I set up a panel indicator to show me what use is being made of the sound hardware (the output of `cat /proc/asound/NVidia/pcm7p/sub0/hw_params`), so when the game starts I can see the output going from `closed` to the usual `S32LE — 6 channels — 48.0kHz`* but nothing comes out of the speakers.

It’s a 32-bit game, but the developer kindly tried a 64-bit build with the same results.

My hopes aren’t high of getting a solution here; just that someone might have seen something similar. Next stop is the Unity forums I suppose.

[I think it would be good for searching if we had a `unity-game-engine` tag here, since it’s used quite a lot, but I don’t have 300 reputation :-(  I’ve seen other posts use `unity` which is misleading.]

*Full output:

`access: MMAP_INTERLEAVED
format: S32_LE
subformat: STD
channels: 6
rate: 48000 (48000/1)
period_size: 1360
buffer_size: 2720`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was entirely caused by a change I made to PulseAudio quite a while back. I added the option `enable-remixing = no` to `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` (the default is `yes`) to prevent Pulse making a surround mix from stereo music. I ended up getting a music player to send the exact music format to my receiver using ALSA anyway, so this setting is redundant.

When set to `no` Pulse drops any channels it can’t match, so some oddity in the Hidden Folks audio caused all output to be dropped.